# Running MySQL as SYSTEM Service in Windows XP

Tags: mysql, windows-xp

I have this strange problem where I create a database in MySQL and I need to restart `mysqld` but I can't seem to do it with info the MySQL docs.  Then, I kill it from the Task Manager and I can't restart it.  When I look at the process, it is run by the SYSTEM, rather than me.  When I run `mysqld` it starts the process by me, not the SYSTEM.  Am I shutting it down incorrectly?  IS there a way to start this daemon as the SYSTEM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Service-Dialog

```
  Right-Click Computer -> Manage -> Service and Application -> Service
```

And restart the service from there.

Or `net stop|start mysql` should work on all Windows OSs, and on newer Server-Versions there's a dedicated tool: `sc stop|start|query mysql`.

Comment: Alternately: Start -> Run -> services.msc

Comment: Thanks!  I think I knew that, but was stuck thinking about the command line.  Cheers.